# What is the difference between dataframe.show() and dataframe.take() in spark? To increase the performance what we need to increase?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using dataframes to read data from parquet files and creating a temporary view and running SQL queries on top the temp views.

`spark.read.parquet("filename.parquet").createOrReplaceTempView("temptable")`

`val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temptable")`

to check the result of `df` i am using `df.show()` but it takes more to execute and I did not see any difference if I use `df.take(10)`

**IS there any difference between `take()` and `show()`.which method should I use for better performance to check the results**

Answer (score 12):

`take()` and `show()` are different. `show()` prints results, `take()` returns a list of rows (in PySpark) and can be used to create a new dataframe. They are both actions.

Print results

```py
df.show()
```

Get list of rows (PySpark)

```py
sampleList = df.take(10)
```